# When/where is it ideal to determine Unsupported Media Type in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

So, I have a Spring MVC application, and I want a way to determine when a resource doesn't support a specific media type.  I was thinking of doing this with custom View Resolvers...  If none of the view resolvers find a successful match for the view name, then throw an exception triggering Unsupported media type (HTTP code of `406`).

This mostly makes sense because most view resolvers will return `null` if it can't resolve the given view name.  The problem arises with view resolvers like `InternalResourceViewResolver` which ALWAYS returns a view, even if the given view name doesn't exist.

Just as a reference, here is what my controllers look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getViewData() {

    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("rightNow", (new Date()).toString());

    return new ModelAndView("foo", "model", myModel);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most of this with [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html), though it sounds like you'll have to extend `InternalResourceViewResolver` if you want it to behave differently depending on the absence of a particular view template.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `@RequestHeader` annotation to define which media types are supported by your method.

Comment: `@RequestHeader` is used to bind controller method arguments to some HTTP header. You can't control the supported media types with this annotation. What you meant is `@RequestMapping(..., produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`.